# How to detect an SSH connection?

Tags: ssh

For some reason I have he following scenario:

On boot-up I'm launching a script which waits for a given amount of time and checks whether an SSH connection was astablished during this time window or not. If a connection is open, the script does action A, else it kills sshd and does B.

What would be the best way to detect an open connection? (The script can be written in Bash or Ruby)

thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to detect a current SSH session, use `lsof -i :22` and look for it returning more than 2 lines or grep for ESTABLISHED:
`[root@nemo ~]# lsof -i :22

COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME

sshd     3772  root    3u  IPv6   9906       TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)

sshd    21376  root    3r  IPv6 159072       TCP myserver:ssh->someip:27813 (ESTABLISHED)

sshd    21381 james    3u  IPv6 159072       TCP myserver:ssh->someip:27813 (ESTABLISHED)`

To see if a session  was opened at all, look for something similar to the following in /var/log/secure (on redhat/centos/fedora):
`Sep 27 05:05:28 nemo sshd[21376]: Accepted password for james from some_ip port 27813 ssh2`
If you allow authentication by means other than password, the log entries may be slightly different.

Comment: public key: `Sep 27 08:49:04 host sshd[13816]: Accepted publickey for user from some_ip port 54966 ssh2`

Comment: For the archives: the log file is /var/log/auth.log in debian/ubuntu.

Comment: Fairly new to linux, but it seems to me something like this might work quite well to get a list of unique connections. Please correct me if I am wrong! `sudo lsof -i :22 | grep -Po '(?<=TCP ).*(?= \(ESTABLISHED\))' | uniq` It could be adjusted to use `| wc -l` on the end for a connection count.

Comment: This one checks for outgoing ssh connections.

Answer (score 3):

```
#client connecting from ${CLIENT_IP} to local ssh listening on SSHD_IP default port

A() {
  echo "A"
}
B() {
  echo "B"
}
CLIENT_IP=""
SSHD_IP=""
sleeptime=5 #use this counter to sleep $sleeptime seconds, decrementing on match fail
while [ ${sleeptime} -gt 0 ] ; do
  netstat -nt |grep -q -E "${CLIENT_IP}:[0-9]+[[:space:]]+${SSHD_IP}:22[[:space:]]+ESTA"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then 
    A; exit 0
  else
    sleeptime=$((${sleeptime} - 1))
    sleep ${sleeptime}
  fi
done
kill -TERM `cat /var/run/sshd.pid`
B
```

Comment: This one checks for incoming ssh connections.